# chef-server - chef-solo - vagrant - puppet... which is correct for me?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, puppet

I have 9 servers in digitalocean.

- one with mysql/mongodb
- one cloudera/hadoop
- one nginx/nodejs/rails
- ...

So, I was read about chef/puppet/vagrant and seems awesome to know I can configure everything in all servers automatically.

All I want is setup more servers automatically with recipes. Maybe this:

- DB-recipe: install mysql and mongodb, configure passwords, users, etc
- LAMP-recipe: install and configure apache, mysql and php automatically
- NodeJS-recipe: install and configure nodeJS and NPM automatically

But I'm still confused. Which of options is the correct for me?

chef-server - chef-solo - vagrant - puppet?

Comment: This is primarily opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also conflicted on this. In the end "Just Get Started" is a good approach. I chose chef-solo and vagrant when deploying a rails app on aws and it has worked well for me. Also this article helped me

he says "If you’re a Rails shop you’d probably go straight to Chef."

https://www.scriptrock.com/blog/puppet-vs-chef-battle-wages/

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe also Ansible? Seems like a few prefer that these days. Over Puppet and Chef. Maybe because of the simplicity. Or Salt? Guess Vagrant is a must for testing your setup locally. Between that, I think Chef and Puppet are just as good and it's up to you who you like best.

And you don't have to do the Puppet-master/Chef-server bit. There are many tutorials with smooth masterless setup. I would do the Getting started for all of the above and then make my choice.

Comment: Vagrant is different, as it's not a config management solution. Instead, yes, it creates virtual machines that can be then provisioned by Chef, Puppet, Ansible, ...
And I'd say a "what's correct for me" question is highly opinion-based. Any of these config mgmt. tools can help.